# Custom Post with Ratings

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, rating-system

I have a custom post with a bunch of information about several people.  I would like to make a portfolio page that shows their work and includes the ability to rate each piece.  How can I make that happen?

Edit:  I've been searching through wordpress rating plugins.  I got one (I believe it was called Post Ratings) to appear below each image but the plugin appears to be broken and not work with the current version of wordpress.

Comment: The question is too broad and does not confer to any research done..

Comment: Please see my edit. i've spent quite  a bit of time reading through plugin descriptions and reviews.  When i found one that seemed suitable i implemented it for testing.  the plugin [Post Rating] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-ratings/) appeared where i want it to but its functionality appears to be broken(confirmed by the support forums.